# Trigger local notification permission dialog from button press in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

What is the correct way to trigger a notification permissions dialog from a button press?

All of the tutorials place the permission dialog trigger in appDelegate so as soon as the application is loaded a permissions dialog appears.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you just answered your own question. Move the code that asks for notification permission to the function that gets called for your button press. It might look something like this:

```
@IBAction func buttonPressed() {
    registerUserNotificationSettings()
}

func registerUserNotificationSettings() {
    let userNotificationTypes = UIUserNotificationType.Alert | UIUserNotificationType.Badge | UIUserNotificationType.Sound
    let settings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: userNotificationTypes, categories: nil)
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
}
```

Comment: but that code seems to only work in the delegate and I've seen a bunch of posts on stackoverflow saying it's bad practice to call a delegate method from a view controller.

Comment: I edited my answer to include a code example. Does that help at all? You do not need to (and probably should not) put this code in the app delegate. In fact, I usually create separate classes to handle registering, creating, and reading notifications.

Comment: thanks!  any chance you know how to pause execution until or trigger execution when a notification permission dialog button is pressed?

Comment: I don't think there is very good support (framework callback handlers) for push notification dialogs. Even so, your app should continue to function whether the user allows notifications or not, so I would try to work your app flow to allow the user to move on when they have responded to the permission alert.

Comment: Exactly, I want to call a segue as soon as they respond but I'm not sure how code that.  It doesn't matter how they respond, I'm still moving to the next view controller.

Comment: In that case, you might be able to perform the segue and pop up the notification permission alert at the same time (both in the button press function). Or when you press the button the first time, pop up the alert and change the text on the button to something else. Then when the user comes back from answering the alert and push the button a second time, that will perform the segue. Just a couple options...